# How To Upload two files in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm trying to upload two file in one submit button using the following code:

```
<label>Logo Image *</label>
<input type="file" name="ufile[]"/>
<label>Banner Image *</label>
<input type="file" name="ufile[]"/>
```

**PHP**

```
$logo = $_FILES['ufile']['name'][0];
$block_img = $_FILES['ufile']['name'][1];

 if ($_FILES['ufile']['name']["error"] > 0) {
    echo "error<br>";
   }
  else {
    if (file_exists("small-image/" .  $_FILES['ufile']['name'][0])){
        echo $_FILES['ufile']['name'][1] . "File already exists in server. ";
    }
    else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ufile']['name'][0], "small-image/" . $_FILES['ufile']['name'][0]);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ufile']['name'][1], "small-image/" . $_FILES['ufile']['name'][1]);
    }
 }

$sql_query = "UPDATE header_img SET logo_img = '$logo', block_img = '$block_img' WHERE banner_id = 1";
```

My database is updating correctly but the file is not uploaded. Yes there is a 777 directory call 'small-image'.

Any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: Do **NOT** use this code. You are leaving your server wide open to a **TOTAL REMOTE TAKEOVER**. You have absolutely no file validation, are using user-provided filenames, etc... A malicious user can use this code to scribble a file **ANYWHERE** on your server. ON top of that, you're vulnerable to SQL injection. You could not write less secure if you set out to do so deliberately.

Comment: Thanks for the instructions but this is actually a test work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `move_uploaded_file`, you want to use `$_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name']`, that's where the file is currently located.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'][0], "small-image/" . $_FILES['ufile']['name'][0]);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'][1], "small-image/" . $_FILES['ufile']['name'][1]);
```

Check the example in the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php